# QUOTENAME without Dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql

I want to use the function `QUOTENAME` without Dynamic SQL.

I have:

```
update [SQL].dbo.customers
set points = 5
where subject = @Subject
```

I would like:

```
update QUOTENAME('SQL') + dbo.Customers
set points = 5
where subject = @Subject
```

I succeed with `Dynamic SQL` but I wanna avoid that.

Comment: Since you cannot parameterize any part of a table name *without* using dynamic SQL, what's the point?

Comment: I put this query into FastReport with: [SQLExp('update XY')]
If xy = [SQL] then this quote close/open SQLExp
So I need:
[SQLExp('update QUOTENAME('SQL') + dbo.Customers ... ')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about another server did you think about using linked server and alias. Then you can use alias in UPDATE and don't have to use QUOTENAME.